# How to avoid multiple log files in slf4j logging?

Tags: java, spring, logging, slf4j

I am implementing SLF4J logging with logback.xml but application is creating multiple log files.
I need to create one single log file for a date with all the log levels in same log files.

Below is my logback.xml configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="LOG_FILE_LOCATION" value="./log/" />

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%thread] [%-5level] [%logger] - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%thread] [%-5level] [%logger] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE_LOCATION}/manageng_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>


    <appender name="FILE-ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%thread] [%-5level] [%logger] - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE_LOCATION}/manageng_error_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>


    <logger name="net.indecomm.manageng" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>


</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simplify it to this:

```
<configuration>
    <property name="LOG_FILE_LOCATION" value="./log/" />

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%thread] [%-5level] [%logger] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE_LOCATION}/manageng_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="net.indecomm.manageng" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But now even more number of log files created with all necessary data which I didn't logged at all.

Comment: the logger name is to filter out log based on package name.

Comment: I want to print only those statements which I logged in either of the levels. Don't want any other statements to be printed in log files. Log file must only one for a day or date.